# GNOME isn't starting after installing FreeBSD 12.1

Tags: freebsd, gui

I've installed a fresh copy of FreeBSD 12.1 on a spare HDD.

I've followed every single instruction on installing GUI on FreeBSD.

First, I've installed Xorg "pkg install Xorg", followed by installing GNOME

```
pkg install gnome3
```

Then I've edited `/etc/fstab` and `rc.conf` to add `proc`, and enabled `dbus`, `hald`, `gdm` and GNOME.

After I rebooted the system the GUI didn't start and I'm only able to use SH shell.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what does `which gdm` return?

Comment: here's the log from 
 cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
https://pastebin.com/YhL3X8nY

Comment: /usr/local/sbin/gdm

Comment: Please explain in the question why you are not following the instructions in chapter 5 of the _FreeBSD Handbook_.

Comment: I'm following the instructions in the handbook

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows that no card/driver was detected. It then falls back to the VESA/framebuffer driver. Your card does however not support VESA and X cannot start.

> [    38.365] (II) scfb: driver for wsdisplay framebuffer: scfb
>
> [    38.366] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
>
> [    38.366] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory

You state you are following the FreeBSD Handbook. The relevant part is [5.4.5](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-config.html#x-config-video-cards) but is rather hard to digest. X has become much better at autodetecting cards. This means that you do not need to fiddle with `xorg.conf` but you do need to make sure that you have updated drivers. This means for a regular user you should install [graphics/drm-kmod](https://www.freshports.org/graphics/drm-kmod).

```
 # pkg install drm-kmod
```

This might allow X to autodetect your card. If not then you need to fiddle with `xorg.conf.d`.

If you are still stuck - then make sure that you card is listed as supported ([Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units)/[AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units) KMS cards).

Comment: If I installed the Nvidia driiver, will it solve the problem?

Comment: Probably - especially if you have a nvidia card :-). `pkg install nvidia-driver` and then add it to `rc.conf` with `sysrc kld_list+="nvidia-modeset"`. See [x11/nvidia-driver](https://www.freshports.org/x11/nvidia-driver). If your card is older then you might instead need [x11/nvidia-driver-304](https://www.freshports.org/x11/nvidia-driver-304) or [x11/nvidia-driver-340](https://www.freshports.org/x11/nvidia-driver-340).